# Using cTakes with UIMA in Java code eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uima, ctakes

I am trying to do NLP using `cTAKES` in Eclipse. I have followed the official developers guide for installing `cTAKES` in Eclipse but I couldnt find any documentation of what to do next i.e how would I import `cTAKES` pipelines or analysisengine etc. in `UIMA` code. I am new to `UIMA` and `cTAKES`. I have also searched for similar questions here, but couldnt find any help. 
Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Note:  I can't use cTAKES-REST api in my problem.

Comment: Apache cTAKES itself uses UIMA framework. So what you really mean by using ctakes in uima code?